# Print Each Line from csv file as new Label

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

So i'm making a BMI Calculator and i have all the data been stored into a csv file
and the raw data is been written like this

> John,1.7,55,19.031141868512112,22/03/2016,
>
> Tony,1.8,55,16.975308641975307,22/03/2016,

I am trying to display these values as Labels which is probably a bad idea..
i have labels along the top of the app like this

> Name   Height   Weight  Bmi  Date

and i would like to print each line of text underneath this and i have been trying to achieve this with a for loop and trying to just get the names by using the .partition until the first "," and just print the name but nothing seems to be working

anyways here is the code

```
__author__ = 'Anon'
from tkinter import *

fr = open('Bmi.csv', 'rb')

for i, line in fr.interitems():
nameList = fr.read()
names = nameList.partition(",")[0]
allNames = Label(text = names).grid(row=2,column=i,sticky=W)





mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry("700x350+200+200")
mGui.title("BMI Calculator - Anon")

nameLable = Label(text = "Name").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)



HeightLable = Label(text = "Height").grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
WeightLable = Label(text = "Weight").grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=W)
BmiLable = Label(text = "Bmi").grid(row=2,column=3,sticky=W)
DateLable = Label(text = "Date").grid(row=2,column=4,sticky=W)


mGui.mainloop()
```

i would like to find an easier way to print these lines and have buttons to delete certain lines and add more lines

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a `Listbox` instead? This seems to be exactly what `Listbox`es were designed for.

Comment: I shall look into this thanks

Comment: A treeview is better than the labels option